# Android FancyCoverFlow - Centered Image has Off-Set on old/smaller Device

Tags: android, offset, deprecated, android-gallery

I have a problem with the `FancyCoverFlow` which extends `Gallery`:

https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow

I want to center the selected Image of the `FancyCoverFlow`. On my 5" Android 4.2 Device it works perfectly. But on my 3.7" Android 2.2 the selected Image has an Off-Set to the left. 
(I prepaired Images, but I can't post them until I does have 10 Reputations xD)

My `FancyCoverFlow` Item in XML looks like this:

```
 <package.FancyCoverFlow
    android:id="@+id/fancyCoverFlow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

    fcf:maxRotation="55"
    fcf:scaleDownGravity="0.8"
    fcf:unselectedAlpha="0.3"
    fcf:unselectedSaturation="0.0"
    fcf:unselectedScale="0.2" >
</package.FancyCoverFlow>
```

The layout of the item I'm displaying in this `FancyCoverFlow` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@android:color/transparent"

  >

 <ImageView
android:id="@+id/horizontal_player_image"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
android:layout_above="@+id/relatLayout"
/>

 <RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/relatLayout"
  android:layout_width="100dp"
  android:layout_height="20dp" 
  android:layout_above="@+id/horizontal_player_name">

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="20dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
      android:src="@drawable/drinkplayeritem" 
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

   <package.BrushTextView
    style="@style/BrushFont"
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_drink_count"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text=""
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    />

   <package.BrushTextView
    style="@style/BrushFont"
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_false_card_count"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text=""
    android:gravity="right"

    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
    />

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="20dp"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      android:src="@drawable/cardsplayeritem" />

 </RelativeLayout>

 <package.BrushTextView
    style="@style/BrushFont"
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_player_name"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="15sp"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I already tried center everything I've found :D `ImageViews` (FitCenter) etc...
Nothing worked. It is so stupid that it works on my newer Device but on the older one not..

Hope someone can help me and maybe had the same issue.

EDIT 1:
Does it results of the `deprecated` class `Gallery?` But if so, why does it work on my newer device? :D

Thanks!